# Form send php data

Tags: php

Some code from me.

```
if (fwrite($create_file, 
"<div class='slud_atr_vieta'>
<font style='color:#666;'>."<?php echo $lang['z_at_vieta'] ?>".:</font> $pilsetas
</div> ") === FALSE)

."<?php echo $lang['z_at_vieta'] ?>". <-- That problem
```

I need this for language change in post, I send variable data, and when user change the language, post variable change.

I put some points and marks `""`, but it wont let me send it.

But I get a PHP error:

```
( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?' in...
```

Comment: You are already in a php context so don't need to put <?php echo  in the middle of the string

Comment: Off topic, but the `font` tag is deprecated, you should switch it out with a span.

Comment: i know, but that information i send to another file, other folder. They make new file, with all information, and he dont change if i send post text.

Answer (score 1):

I see two issues with your code:

1. You're using `<?php` tags multiple times, within the same block. If you're already within the PHP context, you don't need to add it again.
2. You're trying to echo the variable inside `fwrite` function. That's not necessary. Just concatenate the variable with the string.

**Code:**

```
if (fwrite($create_file, 
"<div class='slud_atr_vieta'>
<font style='color:#666;'>". $lang['z_at_vieta'] . ":</font>". $pilsetas ."
</div> ") === FALSE)
?>
<?php echo $lang['z_at_vieta'] ?>
```

Comment: I get it, its so easy :D <?php echo \$lang[\"variable\"] ?> now i can send it to file and all works :)

Answer (score 1):

change to:

```
<?php

if (fwrite($create_file, "<div class='slud_atr_vieta'><font style='color:#666;'>".$lang['z_at_vieta']."</font> $pilsetas</div> ") === FALSE)
    echo $lang['z_at_vieta'];
?>
```

Comment: I send this information, and when i send that to file, like a post he never change language, becouse its looks <div class='slud_atr_vieta'>
<font style='color:#666;'>Город:</font> Aloja</div> But i want change them, and only i can change that if i can send in Город: this <?php echo $lang['variable']; ?>

Comment: then its works, but i cant send that :/

Answer (score 0):

```
if (fwrite($create_file, 
"<div class='slud_atr_vieta'>
<font style='color:#666;'><?php echo \$lang[\"variable\"] ?></font>: $pilsetas
</div> ") === FALSE)
```

Thats work for me, now i can send it like a text, and when it send it to own file, php works great on language change on the new file.